# How to get the nth commit since the first commit?

Tags: git

I can find out how many commits there are with this:

```
git rev-list HEAD --count
```

Let's say that returns 123 commits.

How can I find the nth commit out of 123? Note that I am not asking for the nth commit before HEAD. I would like to know the nth commit after the very first commit.

Comment: is that well-defined in the presence of merges?

Comment: I intend to use this for my release branch when tagging so I don't think merges come into play.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This could be considered ugly but I could not think of a better way

```
$git log --skip=N --max-count=1
```

This will show exactly 1 commit, counting back from HEAD by `N`. To use this you need to provide a number for `N` though. `N` is calculated with

`N = total-commits - desired-commit-nr`

Say `git rev-list HEAD --count` returns 10 and you want to view the 3rd commit

```
$git log --skip=7 --max-count=1
```

We use 7 because

```
 7 = 10 - 3
total ^   ^ the commit we want
```

Comment: Alternatively, if you use `--reverse` you can filter with an external command (`git rev-list --reverse HEAD | sed -n -e 3p` to get 3rd-from-last).  Annoyingly you can't combine this with `--skip` as the skip action occurs *before* the reversing, so you still need to skip 7.  Also, if the rev list is very long, piping through sed just to extract one line is expensive so the above is better.

Comment: simple math defeats me again!